# MongoDB operations rate by collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to get an operation count/rate by collection or database?

I know about `mongotop` command, but it's quite different. Also, it seems `collStats` has no information I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a `top` admin command. [Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/top/) is the doc.

This is how exactly `mongotop` works internally, but `mongotop` calculates total time of operations. With `top` command I can get the count of operations by collection.

```
db.adminCommand("top")
```